# Set backgroud image from the javascript not working

Tags: javascript

In my javascript I have my div svg as following:

```
var svg = d3.select("#"+settings.id).append("svg") 
        .attr("id", "svg")

                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")

                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

And then I added

```
document.getElementById('svg').style.backgroundImage = 'url(myimageUrl)';
```

But it didnt work

Comment: Provide the html code and if possible set a Jsfiddle...

Comment: Are you trying to set a background image on a svg element, or use an svg as a background image ?

Comment: @adeneo : It looks as if this has nothing to do with SVG. It's only an id I guess

Comment: http://jsbin.com/anOXurac/1/edit  in my code version here the backgroud image is in the css I want to do the same from the javascript

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing a variable to, it looks like `myimageurl` should contain a string with the image name like "picture.jpg" if so, you may not pass the variable in quotes, because its a string then.

```
document.getElementById('svg').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myimageUrl+')';
```

another interpretion of the question may be :

it depends on where or better when you execute the line that changes the background color.
when you ecexute it before the svg-variable is inserted to the dom it wont find the id of the element, so be sure to run it after that.